# Multiple images in a single CardView

Tags: java, android

I wonder how does apps like Google Music Play, display 4 images in 1 CardView thumbnail. I have tried acquiring the 4 images and processing them into a single image. Though, that is very slow when I have 20 rows. On the other hand, Google does it very fast. I would appreciate any information that will point me in the right direction.

The CardView thumbnail looks like this:

```
+-----------+
|  1  |  2  |
-------------
|  3  |  4  |
+-----------+
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: keep in mind to load bitmaps efficiently :). for start refer : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: Just put 4 image views into the card view.

Comment: `CardView` extends `FrameLayout` so you can add any other `View` inside it, for example `GridLayout`

Comment: the google play actually use thumbnail , not the full image .
also it maintain cache for that . if you are using piccaso for image loading use fit () it will make the loading faster.

Comment: "I have tried acquiring the 4 images and processing them into a single image."
No need to do image processing.

Comment: There are alots of possible solution for it like u can use the `LinearLayout` and divide the view in **4** equals parts

Comment: can you tell the size of each image on the screen. I might have something for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of layout for your list item and tweak constraints according to your need.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="prent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="prent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="prent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="prent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="prent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="prent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_2"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I was hoping I can actually find a better solution. Though, I did not. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Transforming  bitmaps is always a heavy task and with list view where rendering is a frequent action it perform worse. So it is better to load images with some image manipulation library.

Comment: Yes, I personally use Universal Image Loader library. Though, loading 4 images * 100 CardViews seems something not most devices would handle there would be lag.

Comment: You can do one or two things 
1) down sample the images as  for the 4 images in a single card view don't require high quality images. this link would give good understanding of that. https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-large-bitmaps-efficiently-in-android-66826cd4ad53
2) you can load thumbnails and perform caching using library for smooth performance.

Comment: Down sampling and thumbnails also help you to avoid Out Of Memory errors due to heavy images, which is often in listing with image views.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using `cardview` and `linearlayout`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:scaleType="center" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:scaleType="center" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/status_bar_color"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

outscreen :[image: output screen]

Here am using `linearlayout` weights to equally divide the images `width` and `height`
To know more about linearlayout weight refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

To Generate **Thumbnail Images** Refer
[this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils) OR [this](http://www.rogerethomas.com/blog/generating-square-cropped-thumbnails-in-android-java)

code :

```
Bitmap resized = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(sourceBitmap, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There were too many so I had to pick only one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Glide Library for downloading image.

Download all images and once all images are downloaded, make the merged bitmap and show it to ImageView

`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`res/values/dimens.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_height">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_width">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var imageView : ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view)

        val batchBitmap = BatchBitmap()

        val imageUrls = listOf("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/2uNW4WbgBXL25BAbXGLnLqX71Sw.jpg",
                "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/mzGNXi8ZxH7Uxkcf0gNlGc5XAA6.jpg",
                "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/oH1VvlI8P2cpbK2GX4GMcQdK3Gk.jpg",
                "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/d4qVNJmaFGwctFjkS4RnZ6WPjwp.jpg")

        imageUrls.forEach {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(it)
                    .apply(RequestOptions().override(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_width)/2,
                            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_height)/2))
                    .addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                            Log.e("ExampleApp", "failed to fetch image")
                            return false
                        }

                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable?>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                            resource?.let {
                                batchBitmap.addBitmap((resource as BitmapDrawable).bitmap)
                                batchBitmap.getMergedBitmap()?.let {
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(it)
                                }
                            }

                            return true
                        }

                    })
                    .submit()
        }
    }
}


class BatchBitmap {

    private val bitmaps : MutableList<Bitmap> = mutableListOf()

    fun addBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        if(bitmaps.size == 4) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Only 4 bitmaps are allowed")
        }
        bitmaps.add(bitmap)
    }

    fun getMergedBitmap(): Bitmap? {
        return if(bitmaps.size == 4){
            val mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmaps[0].width.times(2), bitmaps[0].height.times(2), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            val canvas = Canvas(mergedBitmap)

            for(index in bitmaps.indices) {
                val bitmap = bitmaps[index]
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps[index], index.rem(2).times(bitmap.width).toFloat(), index.div(2).toFloat().times(bitmap.height), null)
            }
            return mergedBitmap
        }
        else  null
    }
}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: let me know if anything needs to be explained.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There were too many so I had to pick only one.